# Why do $ x$ and $y$ have negative values in this graph of $\tan \theta=y/x$?

Tags: trigonometry

The author defines $\tan (\theta)$ to be $y/x$ where $x$ and $y $are points on a ray making the angle theta from the origin. Using this definition, it seems that the graph of the equation $\tan(\theta)=y/x$ should only be in the first quadrant if theta is less than $\pi/2$; however the author goes on to draw the graph in the third quadrant as well. Why is this the case when the points from which tan(theta) is drawn are only on a ray starting from the origin? So it seems the graph should only exist in one quadrant.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Because if $(x,y)$ satisfies the equation $\tan\theta = y/x$, then so does $(-x,-y)$ since $y/x = (-y)/(-x)$.

The author explicitly says "any point ... satisfying this equation is a point on the line...". That's the line shown in the figure.